# Silverlight Wcf method receives the exception even after the WCF service executed successfully

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, iis-5

About my application:

Application built in silver light. It upload the file into server and reads all the records from the file and validates it and Inserts into database table.
The below issue occurs only when I run the application in IIS and upload the large file having 50,000 records.

When I host the application in IIS and browse the application with machine name then Wcf service returns an error even after service is executed successfully.
Wcf service is successfully returns by inserting all the data into database table but when it reaches to silver light completed event it shows exception.

But strange is when I browse the application using "localhost" it works properly.

Application is hosted using IIS 5 and Set Windows Authentication.

Comment: In WCF sometimes you have to expand the maximum bytes sent and, independently the bytes received. Did that?

Comment: There is no issue in file uploading because file upload is implemented using Httphandler. Exceptions is occurring when i am inserting the record into database. Wcf call is lost when service slow to respond back to silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the WCF Binding timeout (sendTimeout)